# all eigenvalues of a large sparse symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-methods

my question is similar to

[How to diagonalize a large sparse symmetric matrix to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12179/how-to-diagonalize-a-large-sparse-symmetric-matrix-to-get-the-eigenvalues-and-e)

however i wish to be more concrete and ask if one can, on a standard PC 
(e.g. a 500$ laptop :)) and using existing libraries, find all eigenvalues 
of a 50,000x50,000 sparse (up to 5 entries in a row) symmetric positive 
semidefinite matrix (to be again more concrete, a graph Laplacian), 
and how reliable this computation might be.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual methods?  First reduce the matrix to tridiagonal form using orthogonal similarity (possibly Givens rotations will be more efficient in your application than Householder transformations).  Then apply shifted-QR or Lanczos methods to isolate the eigenvalues.  Since these are iterative methods, and you can always return to your original matrix for refinement, I don't see a reliability issue.  However you are asking for 50,000 eigensolutions, and that's going to be a long running calculation.

Comment: thank you, I cannot upvote your comment for technical reasons, but for me it is a helpful information.

Comment: Is this a 2D Laplacian on a regular grid?

Comment: For Questions in Math.SE it's better to focus on the math aspects of your problem rather than hardware or software issues; those will likely be considered off-topic in this forum.

Comment: There is a serious problem with the "usual methods", in that they do not make use of the fact that your matrices are sparse. With minimal googling I found a survey at http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/documentation/reports/str6.pdf.

Comment: @hardmath: yes, it is a regular grid. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Chris Godsil: thank you for the reference; I beleive that hardmath suggested methods which deal precisely with sparse matrices. I am aware that there are many libraries which can be used to do such calculations: what I was trying to understand is whether these libraries may deal with a problem of the indicated size on a simple personal computer.

Comment: @Giovanni Rossi: your intent was quite clear. My point is that is that the standard methods for bringing a matrix to tridiagonal form do not preserve sparsity in the intermediate stages.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: You state a good point.  After all, we start with five nonzero entries per row, and tridiagonalization only drops this to three!  One can apply Lanczos algorithms (another type of tridiagonalization method) immediately and get some quick information about extreme eigenvalues.  I'm sure someone has a paper about this for the five-point difference scheme, a classic example; just haven't spotted it yet.

Comment: @hardmath: Tridiagonalized matrices are sparse, but as far as I can see there is no guarantee that the matrices that arise in the intermediate stages of the tridiagonaliztion process are sparse.

Comment: @Chris Godsil: thank you again for the reference and information.